# Is it possible to cut the first four characters in while reader on c#

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

Is there possible to cut first four characters in while loop.. ?

```
 MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand($"CALL nearest3({GlobalLat}, {GlobalLong},1)", connection);

            using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    // access your record colums by using reader
                    LabelPlace.Text = (reader[0]).ToString();
                    SearchLocation = LabelPlace.Text;
                }
            }
```

I want to cut first four characters on `LabelPlace.Text`

Answer (score 0):

Use `LabelPlace.Text.Substring(3)`. See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-5.0)

Comment: or `LabelPlace.Text = (reader[0]).ToString().Substring(3)`

Comment: Indeed we do not know exactly which string has to be cut